# make consultation with more combinations of values with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, logic

My logic is I have two tables say table A and table B, right ?

information is the name of the table A to table B has, say the value that will be consulted

I will give an example

Structure Table A

```
id | title
------------------------------------------------------
1  | Iphone 5
2  | Galaxy S4
```

Structure Table B

```
id | id_table_A| value|
-------------------------
1  | 1;2 | TV     |
2  | 1;2 | led    |
3  | 2   | samsung|
4  | 1   | apple  |
5  | 1   | android|
6  | 1   | iOS    |
7  | 1   | 4GB    |
8  | 1   | 64GB   |
```

up there with no problems, if I do a query of values ​​ta table B, it will show normally, but the problem is I need to store other identifications (id_table_A) I wanted to separate it by commas.

the script should show the title of the table with the most correct values ​​of Table B

Here is an example of how it should work

values ​​entered:

```
1º - 4GB
2º - led
3º - android 
4º - TV
```

then it should show the first Galaxy S4 and then shows the iphone
comes when the result should show the order which has more values ​​associated with table A
also noticed that I used, to separate the id?

Comment: Never ever store delimited strings of values! Normalize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please normalize your data. It will pay off big time in the long run letting you normally querying and maintaining your data.

Proposed schema might look like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE products
(
  `id` int, 
  `title` varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE tags
(
  `id` int, 
  `value` varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE product_tag
(
  `product_id` int, 
  `tag_id` int
);
```

Sample data (based on yours):

```
products:           tags:             product_tag:

| ID |     TITLE |  | ID |   VALUE |  | PRODUCT_ID | TAG_ID |
------------------  ----------------  -----------------------
|  1 |  Iphone 5 |  |  1 |      TV |  |          1 |      1 |
|  2 | Galaxy S4 |  |  2 |     led |  |          2 |      1 |
                    |  3 | samsung |  |          1 |      2 |
                    |  4 |   apple |  |          2 |      2 |
                    |  5 | android |  |          2 |      3 |
                    |  6 |     iOS |  |          1 |      4 |
                    |  7 |     4GB |  |          2 |      5 |
                    |  8 |    64GB |  |          1 |      6 |
                                      |          2 |      7 |
                                      |          1 |      8 |
```

Now to get products that have one or more of these tags ('4GB', 'led', 'android', 'tv') ordered by the number of associated tags (rank) you can use a query like this

```sql
SELECT p.*
  FROM products p JOIN 
(
  SELECT pt.product_id, COUNT(*) rank
    FROM product_tag pt JOIN tags t
      ON pt.tag_id = t.id
   WHERE t.value IN ('4GB', 'led', 'android', 'tv')
   GROUP BY pt.product_id
) q ON p.id = q.product_id
 ORDER BY q.rank DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |     TITLE |
------------------
|  2 | Galaxy S4 |
|  1 |  Iphone 5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be501/1)** demo

Comment: this is great, but entries will be listed by a combobox you do not think it will repeat?

Comment: What entries exactly and why they should be repeated in UI?

Comment: @offboard Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: I do not think it is a good base, I know when I'm finished my database, which is very large